# Visual Studio 2008 and JavaScript brackets formatting

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

As we all know MS added JavaScript formatting to VS 2008 SP1. But unfortunately it fails on this code:

```
var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
            layout: "border",
            items: [{
                region: "center",
                contentEl: "center"
            }, {
                region: "south",
                contentEl: "south"
            }, {
                region: "west",
                contentEl: "west"
}] // This bracket is misplaced
            });

            viewport.render();
```

Is there any way to fix it? Is it fixed in VS 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find any way to fix it, but it is fixed in VS 2010.